# Access current scope in own tag in DotLiquid

Tags: c#, dotliquid

When I loop though an IEnumerable in my DotLiquid template

```
{% for block in Blocks -%}

    // this works
    {{ block.Structure }}

    // this doesn't
    {% RenderObject block.Structure %}

{% endfor -%}
```

I can render a member directly via `block.Structure` but I don't know how to access this Structure object in my own tag class `RenderObject`:

```
public class RenderObject : Tag
{
    private string _tagName;
    private string _markup;

    public override void Initialize(string tagName, string markup, List<string> tokens)
    {
        _tagName = tagName;
        _markup = markup.Trim();
        base.Initialize(tagName, markup, tokens);
    }

    public override void Render(Context context, TextWriter result)
    {
        // HERE COMES THE QUESTION
        // How to access the block.Structure object here?
        var structure = ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `context` object that's passed in to your `RenderObject.Render` method. There's an indexer on `Context` that resolves variable names into variables. (And the `For` tag places the loop variable, i.e. `block` in your example, into the `context`.)

The remaining problem is getting the variable name ("block.Structure"). Fortunately, that's exactly what the `markup` variable, passed in to `RenderObject.Initialize`, is there for.

So this should work:

```
public class RenderObject : Tag
{
    private string _tagName;
    private string _markup;

    public override void Initialize(string tagName, string markup, List<string> tokens)
    {
        _tagName = tagName;
        _markup = markup.Trim();
        base.Initialize(tagName, markup, tokens);
    }

    public override void Render(Context context, TextWriter result)
    {
        var structure = context[_markup];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes you are right but that is a `DropProxy` object and I actually have to check if the "proxied" object implements a specific interface of my app. Is there a way to access the object? Because I know the importance of the Proxy for security in the template but it would be great to access the "real" object in my RenderObject tag?

Comment: That's a different question :) The normal solution would be to create your own `Drop`-derived class, which would let you implement whatever interfaces you like. Or you could roll your own version of `DropProxy`, and register it with `Template.RegisterSafeType(myType, x => new MyDropProxy(x))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I came up with changing the DotLiquid assembly and registering my application so I can access the DotLiquid internals from there - because you already have a `.GetObject()` method in your DropProxy... :)